# How to detect location in device's current location mode since API level < 19 (Kitkat)

Tags: android

It is possible to get the device's current location mode since API level 19 (Kitkat):

```
public int getLocationMode(Context context)
{
return Settings.Secure.getInt(activityUnderTest.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);

}

0 = LOCATION_MODE_OFF
1 = LOCATION_MODE_SENSORS_ONLY
2 = LOCATION_MODE_BATTERY_SAVING
3 = LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY
```

### What i want to know:

- How to detect location in device's current location mode since API
  level < 19 (Kitkat).
- Is it possible ?
- If not what is the work around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely it's possible, but the reported values will be a bit different. Prior to KitKat, this information was accessed by determining which location providers were enabled via `LocationManager`. There are two primary providers: GPS and Network.

- `LocationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER).isEnabled()` would describe if the user had enabled/disabled GPS access in location settings. This is roughly the same as having `LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY`.
- `LocationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).isEnabled()`would describe if the user had enabled/disabled network sources in location settings. This is roughly the same as having `LOCATION_MODE_BATTERY_SAVING`
- If both providers are disabled, you're basically at `LOCATION_MODE_OFF`

It's not a 1:1 mapping, but it ought to be close enough for most use cases. Be aware that `getProvider()` can also return `null` if that provider doesn't exist (e.g. the device doesn't have a GPS chip), so you'll have to manage that case as well.